# Passing a component as props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a class `ShowPreview` which renders a preview of web camera. I'm trying to make a `RenderOnClick` class that renders a component based on a condition.

I'm trying to pass to `RenderOnClick` a class which is will render? How can I do this?

I'm doing this so I don't have to code the condition every time.

ShowPreview

```
class ShowPreview extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return (<QrReader/>)
    }
}
```

RenderOnClick

```
class RenderOnClick extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = ({buttonName: this.props.buttonName, element: this.props.element, isRendered: false})
    }
    render(){
        if(isRendered == false){
            return(<button>{this.state.buttonName}</button>)
        }else{
            return (this.state.element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) when you referred passing a component to another.

A sample code taken from above link

```
function SplitPane(props) {
  return (
    <div className="SplitPane">
      <div className="SplitPane-left">
        {props.left}
      </div>
      <div className="SplitPane-right">
        {props.right}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <SplitPane
      left={
        <Contacts />
      }
      right={
        <Chat />
      } />
  );
}
```

What you can do is pass component as props as in the example mentioned in the link and use it in your RenderOnclick component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which takes the element you would like to conditionally render, like so:

example: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwmx4y8q10)

```
    const RandomElemement = () => <div>Foo!</div>;
    const whenClicked = (WrappedElement) => {
      return class RenderOnClick extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = ({ 
            buttonName: this.props.buttonName,
            element: this.props.element, 
            isRendered: false })
        }
        handleClick = () => {
          this.setState(prev => ({isRendered: !prev.isRendered}));
        }
        render() {
          const { isRendered } = this.state;
          if (isRendered === false) {
            return (<button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.buttonName}</button>)
          } else {
            return (<WrappedElement />);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    const App = () => {
      const WhenClicked = whenClicked(RandomElemement);
      return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
        <WhenClicked buttonName='show foo'/>
        </div>
    )
    };

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it probably solves the problem but I have hard time understanding the syntax you are typing in. :/